# Change element height if it overflows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jQuery and I have an accordion widget. I place content inside each container dynamically. I will like the accordion to grow (height increase) as I place new content inside a new control. My accordion control looks like:

[image]

I initialize my projects accordion widget as:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                navigation: true,
                collapsible: true,
                fillSpace: true

            });
```

As I place HTML inside that accordion with Ajax dynamically you can see that the elements start overflowing. I don't want to see the scroll bars.

So I was thinking of dong something like:

```
somehow with JavaScript see if an element on the dom is overflowing (has the scroll bar)

if it does then increase it's height by 10 px until it does not overflow.
```

I know I can set a fix height but I don't know how much html content I will be placing in each accordion in advance. What do you guys suggest on how to deal with this overflowing issue?

### EDIT

It will be nice if I could resolve this with CSS since I construct the accordion widget dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I been working on it and I have:

```
function removeOverflow(element){
     var newHeight = $(element).height() + element.offsetHeight; 
    $(element).height(newHeight+"px")  // set the hight of the overflowing element
}
```

Comment: This is elegant enough. However, I think you could just use `var newHeight = element.scrollHeight;`

Answer (score 1):

After you have added the content, call;

```
$("#accordion").accordion( "resize" );
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Inspect the div that is overflowing with firebug / chrome tools.  Is it the actual accordian that has overflow:auto set?

Comment: If not (or even if it was, though it could lead to other problems) you could set this in your CSS to overflow:none

Comment: yeah the method I just posted solves that problem but it will be nicer to resolve it like the methods you've been posting. Thanks for the help I think I will stick to to method I just posted and I will have to change a lot my JavaScript...